# App Crashing with EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, crash, crash-reports

I've been receiving Firebase Crash reports and I'm not sure what is causing the crash. I've been unable to replicate the error by testing it in Xcode, but the crash is affecting several different users, so I know it's not an individual device specific crash. Below is everything I know about what is occurring during the crash. However, obviously since this is being reported through Firebase's crash reporting I only have so much information.

1. All the crashes come from some kind of iPad device, which may or may not be a coincidence.
2. I can tell from the event logs that this same crash on different screens for different users, so the crash probably is somewhere in the AppDelegate class, but I'm not sure what kind of problem would only occur occasionally like this crash.
3. The only point in the crash trace that I recognise as being something that I coded is the `main (AppDelegate.swift:15)` however line five in my AppDelegate file is simply the AppDelegate class declaration like so:

   `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`

So I'm not sure what could be wrong with this section.

Let me know if there is any specific information you think might be relevant to the crash and I will endeavour to provide it where possible.

The crash trace:

```
Exception name: EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION

1
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess + 1224112
2
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_exception_throw + 32636
3
UIKit
-[UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin] + 9835108
4
UIKit
__71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke + 3628972
5
UIKit
__56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 3621060
6
UIKit
_runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 2912452
7
UIKit
_cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 2968188
8
UIKit
_afterCACommitHandler + 26016
9
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 919332
10
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 910536
11
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun + 911608
12
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 35916
13
GraphicsServices
GSEventRunModal + 49284
14
UIKit
UIApplicationMain + 516228
15
Poker
main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
16
libdyld.dylib
start + 10420
```

Comment: Could you post the code where breakpoint point to?

Comment: @aircraft the `main (AppDelegate.swift:15)` just points to the AppDelegate class declaration so nothing interesting going on there.

Comment: do you use all exception breakpoint?

Comment: Please put in some breakpoints to see how far the app gets before crashing. Start by putting one in the AppDelegate->didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and right at FIRApp.configure(). Then add one maybe in your first viewController. Once we know how far the app get's we can narrow the crash. However, it looks like it's being caused inside the closure of a Firebase observe call.

Comment: @aircraft this is not an issue i've been able to replicate in Xcode. Its being reported from actual users through Firebase Crash Reporting.

Comment: @jay see above comment.

Comment: Understood. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This error could be a whole bunch of things and this forum is not really an error code troubleshooting forum. We need actual code to work with, otherwise it's guesswork. If you can isolate it down to a section of code, it would *really* help us to help you.

Comment: @Jay Ok, and based on this error trace, where would you suggest I look in my code? Because I'm not really working with much more information that you are here. Also, what do you mean specifically by a "whole bunch of things"? Do you have an actual list in mind?

Comment: There about 1000 different things that could cause it. I already provided pretty specific instructions in a prior comment so if you could at least do that and update your question we may be able to track down the cause.

Comment: @jay I've tried to make the description more complete. If you have any specific suggestions on how I can further illuminate the problem for others, feel free to suggest.

Comment: NSException crashes provide a message explaining what the exception _is_. What is that message?

Comment: @matt where would I find that information?

Comment: I can't help but add to all the comments by @Jay & Co: Kindly read the question next time before adding (somewhat rude) comments. If the question is how to find the code, where the error hides, when only the given call trace is available, there is little point in demanding to see the impossible.

Comment: @marco Please read [What Topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), in particular 1) which this question clearly is. Then read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We read questions very carefully and assist when possible. However, this question falls outside the scope of this forum, per the links above as it's not *duplicatable*. We need enough information to help and are not provided that so we ask for more information.

Comment: @Jay Ok, thanks for the links, which are good for somebody like me to read. I am not supposed to misuse comments as a chat instrument. So, to conclude the discussion on my end: To me, the question asks about a "software tools commonly used by programmers" and the debugging help sought is specified as specifically as possible. Enough to let me provide an answer that cost me hours to discover and is likely to help the asker. If you want to make a power play out of this by ranking my answer down, so be it. No hard feelings. Just a little sadness that honest, helpful help results in...this.

Comment: @marco Not sure what you are talking about. Did you provide a clear answer that solves the OP's issue? I am not seeing in the crash logs the issue has anything to do with Firebase, and since there is no code provided (even an example Firebase function) it's all totally guesswork.

Comment: OP - did you enable debug logging and perhaps dump it to a text file? [Firebase Debug Logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#setloggingenabled)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and this is just a partial answer.

As someone suggested in the comments already, AppDelegate is just close to the root of the call chain that is causing your problem. The problem happens all the way up in that chain, when the system tries to do `_initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview`.

Naturally, you are interested in *your* lines of code that cause the problem. Those are likely somewhere in between the `UIKit`-related lines of calls reported. I don't know how to use the given stack trace directly to get to the root of your (or my) code that causes the problem.

However, I do know how to get closer to those lines. I had an unexpected NSException that showed up in [Firebase Crash reporting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/) with a cryptic call stack similar to yours and a message on top like so:

[image]

Clicking the upload link in the screenshot shown gives this:
[image]

By following the [instructions from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) and quite a bit or research how to get a hold of the dSYMS symbol files relating to the app version in which the problem occurs (I am using Bitcode, which complicates things a bit; I ended up going to iTunes Connect and doing a *Download dSYMS* in the app's *Activities* section), I managed to upload the right symbol files. (Do a `mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == *"` on your local machine to see whether you have the required UUID-identified symbol file already available.)

The call stack that Firebase then showed is this:
[image]

The next time the problem occurred (I just received a respective email from Firebase), I am seeing this:
[image]

The only problem I am now left with is this: The code that seems to cause the problem is rather simple and does not cause any problems in local testing. It's just showing some text view for a static number of rows that I can manually tap and verify.

I am trying to wrap the code in a `do { ... } catch let error { ... }` now to see whether — in a future app version yet to be uploaded — I can catch the internal error with it and report error message and some other details via Firebase error reporting.